# Using thousands separator in the code

Tags: c#

My code requires bunch of large constant values. The definition would be much easier to read if thousands separators could be used in declarations. Is there any better way to declare the weight variables than conversion of a string (i.e. `Convert.ToDouble("1,987,123.456")`)?

Note: there are many questions/answers related **output** format, but no luck identifying anything for the C# code itself.

Comment: C# 7 adds what you want with digit separators `var bigNumberSplit = 123_456_789_012_345_678;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use Visual Studio 2017, there's a new feature in [c# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) exactly for this:

> C# 7.0 allows _ to occur as a digit separator inside number literals

So, you can use:

```
1_987_123.456;
```

But those are *constants*. Don't put them inside a `string` because they will be taken as part of it (not that there's any reason to hard-code a `double` inside a `string`, anyway).